# Simple Flask API backend to maintain a word list

Tags: python, flask, crud

I made a little toy project last semester. I would like to get some insights about my code, particularly the part of handling the database. It is a CRUD kind of traditional API.

```
def fword(lon,lat,radius,ids):
    try:
        result = {}
        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM wordlocation WHERE ((longitude-%s)*(longitude-%s)+(latitude-%s)*(latitude-%s))<%s",(lon,lon,lat,lat,radius))
        words = []
        for row in c.fetchall():
            t = {}
            if row[0] in ids:
                continue
            t["name"] = row[1]
            t["definition"] = row[4]
            t["id"] = row[0]
            t["lat"] = row[2]
            t["long"] = row[3]
            words.append(t)
        result["words"] = words
        j = json.dumps(result)
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        return j
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e))

def pword(lat,lng,word,definition):
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO wordlocation (word,longitude,latitude,definition,lang) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
        (thwart(word),lat,lng,thwart(definition),'english'))
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        return "success!"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e))

def cword(word, username):
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        blank_word = " " + word
        c.execute("UPDATE userstat SET completed=CONCAT(IFNULL(completed,''), %s) , score=score+1 WHERE username=%s;",(blank_word, username))
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        return "successful collect"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e))

def stat(username):
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM userstat WHERE username=%s", (username,))
        dict = {}
        u = c.fetchone()
        dict['username'] = username
        dict['words'] = str(u[1]).split()
        dict['score'] = u[2]
        return json.dumps(dict)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e))
```

The backend logic:

```
@app.route("/getWord", methods=['GET'])
def getWord():
    if 'long' in request.args and 'lat' in request.args and 'radius' in request.args and 'ids' in request.args:
        try:
            longitude = float(request.args["long"])
            latitude = float(request.args["lat"])
            radius = float(request.args["radius"])
            ids = request.args.getlist("ids")
        except:
            return "Bad Request Parameters"
        try:
            allwords_json = fword(longitude,latitude,radius,ids)
            return allwords_json
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(str(e))
    else:
        return "bad request"

@app.route("/postWord",methods=["GET","POST"])
def postWord():
    if 'lat' in request.args and 'long' in request.args and 'word' in request.args and 'definition' in request.args:
        try:
            lat = float(request.args['lat'])
            lng = float(request.args['long'])
            word = str(request.args['word'])
            definition = str(request.args['definition'])
            return pword(lat,lng,word,definition)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(str(e))
    else:
        return "badPost"
```

There are many other endpoints that is in a similar fashion. One issue I am aware of is the variable naming seems not readable.

Comment: *"the variable naming seems not readable"* - have you tried to do anything about that? It doesn't seem reasonable to ask people to spend their time suggesting more changes if you haven't bothered to action the ones you're aware of.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I will react to this issue when I get the chance during spring break. I am just gathering the ideas I should be working on during the spring break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory reference to [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You have incorrect whitespace, for example, and (worse) it's inconsistent:

```
@app.route("/getWord", methods=['GET'])
                    # ^ yes
@app.route("/postWord",methods=["GET","POST"])
                     # ^ preferably not, but *definitely* be consistent
```

---

```
if 'long' in request.args and 'lat' in request.args and 'radius' in request.args and 'ids' in request.args:
```

Would be neater as:

```
if all(arg in request.args for arg in ['long', 'lat', 'radius', 'ids']):
```

This also allows you to extract a `REQUIRED_ARGS` constant if you wish.

---

Your exception handling is too broad. For example:

```
try:
    lat = float(request.args['lat'])
    lng = float(request.args['long'])
    word = str(request.args['word'])
    definition = str(request.args['definition'])
    return pword(lat,lng,word,definition)
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(str(e))
```

You should have as little as possible inside the `try` block, and [avoid bare `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/).

What could actually go wrong inside the `try` block? E.g. for the first two lines, given that you've already checked for the keys, only a `ValueError` would get thrown. And as you have similarly broad error handling in `pword`, you'd only get an error out of that line if the logger itself failed.

Also note that there's a `logging.exception` that actually takes an error object and deals with the traceback correctly.

---

You note correctly that the naming is poor. It is also, again, inconsistent:

```
def fword(lon,lat,...
def pword(lat,lng,...
```

These parameters have the same meaning, so should have the same name (and ideally the same order). Given that you'd always expect the pair, you could even use a `(latitude, longitude)` tuple as e.g. a `coords` argument. Also:

```
def pword(...):
def postWord():
```

---

Finally you have a bunch of functions that all create a `c`ursor and `conn`ection, and two of them are almost identical but for the query string and arguments. Look into whether you could reduce duplication by abstracting those similarities out.

Comment: thank you for your time! definitely will improve on these points and follow pep 8 guide